# How to fix submit form glitch?

Tags: html, css

I need help with fixing this. When I start typing on the form, The Name and Email tag goes up [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7CH5.png) and I can type. But if I refresh the page, the text I typed remains with the Name and Email tag over it [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEbxN.png).

Here's the code. Any help with HTML and CSS would be appreciated. 
P.S. Sry I'm pasting everything, Idk which is what.

```css
.work-request--information{
    display:-webkit-box;
    display:-webkit-flex;
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:flex;
    width:100%;
    -webkit-box-pack:justify;
    -webkit-justify-content:space-between;
    -ms-flex-pack:justify;
    justify-content:space-between;
    margin-bottom:60px
}
.work-request--information .information-name,.work-request--information .information-email{
    position:relative;
    width:45%;
    height:50px;
    font-size:30px;
    font-weight:300;
}
.work-request--information input[type="text"],.work-request--information input[type="email"]{
    width:100%;
    padding:0 0 5px 0;
    background-color:transparent;
    border:none;
    border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
    border-radius:0
}
.work-request--information input[type="text"]:focus,.work-request--information input[type="email"]:focus{
    outline:none;
    background-color:#fff;
}
.work-request--information label{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    pointer-events:none;
    -webkit-transition:top .2s ease-in-out,font-size .2s ease-in-out;
    transition:top .2s ease-in-out,font-size .2s ease-in-out
}
.work-request--information input:focus+label,.work-request--information input.has-value+label{
    top:-15px;
    font-size:14px
}
```

```html
<form class="work-request" action="mailto:example@gmail.com">
  <div class="work-request--information">
    <div class="information-name">
      <input id="name" type="text" spellcheck="false">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="information-email">
      <input id="email" type="email" spellcheck="false">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Send Request">
</form>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please update it to a [mcve]

Comment: this requires some script work

Comment: I'm not sure what a snippet is. If u meant clean it up, I did. See if it's easier to make sense. @Viira

Comment: @DeependuAjish A snippet is a tool in StackOverflow's text editor that allows people to run your code directly from your question (or answer). It is really useful as people can test the current behavior quickly and deliver an answer sooner.

Comment: @Seblor Ty for the help. I'm super new to this.

Comment: check input value on document ready, if value isn't empty add the selectors to elements like if user has insert those values

Comment: @M0ns1f I wish I could understand what you said.. but I started learning HTML like 5 days ago. Would you mind explaining it a little bit more in detail.. I can understand if you don't have the time, but I'd really appreciate it XP.

Comment: try this https://w3bits.com/labs/css-floating-labels/

Comment: @Deependu, how do you submit your form ?, what server laungage are you usine ?

Comment: @M0ns1f I got to know from my previous post that I can't submit my form just using HTML. So I won't be trying that. I just wanted to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can check if an input value is empty, after that add a selector to apply the style needed to make the label float :

```
$(function(){
     $('.work-request--information input').each(function(){
          if($(this).val() != '' && $(this).val() != undefined ){
       $(this).closest('div[class^="information"]').addClass('hasValue');
          }
      })
 })
```

then create css class .hasValue to change the label position and font-size.

But remember to remove it when user empty input value.

Comment: Is this possible on HTML? without JQuery or java?

Comment: Html is a markup laungage it is used only for visualising, there is no logic in it